# Parse Date time with respect to time zone provided in input string

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am trying to understand parsing utc time with time zone information but my code giving me weird results or at least I am not understanding that.

```
var utcTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-05-20T13:00:00Z", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
// utcTime = {5/20/2019 1:00:00 PM} (its kind is Utc and this is accepted)

var zonedTime1 = DateTime.Parse("2019-05-20T13:00:00-04:00", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
//zonedTime1 = {5/20/2019 1:00:00 PM} (its kind is Local, but I was expecting {5/20/2019 9:00:00 AM} with Local kind)

var zonedTime2 = DateTime.Parse("2019-05-20T13:00:00+04:00", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
//zonedTime2 = {5/20/2019 5:00:00 AM} (its kind is Local, but I was expecting {5/20/2019 5:00:00 PM} with Local kind)
```

I wanted to know where I am going wrong or where my expectations are wrong. If utcTime is correctly parsed then why zonedTime1 and zonedTime2 are coming incorrect?

Comment: What is your machine's timezone and what you are using to look at the values? (While [edit] consider adding `WriteLine( zonedTime2.ToString(????))` with whatever format you are using, starting with "o" is good idea).

Comment: Your results seem to agree with you being in the -4 timezone. I think that's eastern time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset in an ISO 8601 timestamp describes the offset from UTC that has *already* been adjusted in the local time portion.  Thus:

- `2019-05-20T13:00:00-04:00` = `2019-05-20T17:00:00Z` = `2019-05-20T13:00:00-04:00`
- `2019-05-20T13:00:00+04:00` = `2019-05-20T09:00:00Z` = `2019-05-20T05:00:00-04:00`

From your expected results, I believe you intended the `13:00:00` to be the UTC value in all three cases, but it is not.

A couple of other things:

- Passing `null` for the culture is the same as passing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.  You're better off passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for ISO 8601 timestamps, as it will both improve performance and prevent bugs when the current culture uses a non-Gregorian calendar system.
- When parsing to a `DateTime`, if there is *any* offset present in the input string, then the result will be adjusted to the local time zone.  The original offset will be taken into account in the conversion, but it will not be preserved.  Thus in many cases you are better off using a `DateTimeOffset` type instead.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, (+04:00 or -04:00) shows the time zone and DateTime.Parse converts it back to local time

Comment: It shows the offset from UTC for that particular point in time, from some time zone somewhere in the world. It may be from the local time zone, or from some other time zone.  Also that offset doesn't uniquely identify a time zone, nor is it always going to be the same number for the same time zone.   See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  But yes, `DateTime.Parse` will see the offset and assume you want a local time result.